# UITableViewCell no being dequeued properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`enter code here`I know, there are a ton of posts like this, but my cell's are not being dequeued properly. Anything I might be missing? I always do it like this, and world! I'm not sure what I might be getting wrong in this case.

```
static NSString *FSStandardFormCellIdentifier = @"FSStandardFormCell";
FSStandardFormCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FSStandardFormCellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell was not dequeued");
    cell = [[FSStandardFormCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:FSStandardFormCellIdentifier];
}
```

Here's my custom initializer:

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([FSStandardFormCell class]) owner:self options:nil][0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by my cell's are not being dequeued properly?

Comment: I do some english mistakes now and then. They were not being dequeued at all. Fixed now.

Comment: so when you enter initWithReuseIdentifier you get nil for self?ž

Comment: Voted to close, problem caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

My Cell Identifier, defined in interface builder did not match the cell identifier in:

```
static NSString *FSStandardFormCellIdentifier = @"FSStandardFormCellIdentifier";
```

After that, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([FSStandardFormCell class]) owner:self options:nil][0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is so wrong. On so many different levels.

Look, I'm not going to go in detail on why this code will make most people's eyes bleed, but in your particular case just use this code to solve your problem:

```
static NSString *FSStandardFormCellIdentifier = @"FSStandardFormCell";
FSStandardFormCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FSStandardFormCellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell was not dequeued");
    cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([FSStandardFormCell class]) owner:nil options:nil][0];
}
```

Comment: I changed to your suggestion, and then changed back, because I need to do some custom initialisation that is not explicit here. Is it because I'm calling super on the custom initialiser, without needing to?

Comment: No, you should call super. What you're doing is overriding your call to super by this line `self = [[NSBundle mainBundle]...`. If you want to do the custom initialization, still do the same approach I've suggested for you, but define a new method inside your table cell `- (void)awakeFromNib` and perform your initialization in it.

Comment: It feels strange to call super, if we're calling loadNibNamed: anyways. Would this be more appropriate? a custom method. -(id)loadFromNib { return [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([FSStandardFormCell class]) owner:self options:nil][0]; }

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how subclassing works. In initialization methods you HAVE to call super. And `-awakeFromNib` is called automatically when you load your view via loadNibNamed method so you could perform additional customization on it.

Comment: I do understand how subclassing works. But if loadFromNib returns an object, then a constructor must have been called somehow?